# Issue with the dimension of matrix being optimised in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dimensions

I am attempting to calculate some weights in order to perform an indirect treatment comparison using R. I have altered some code slightly, in order to reflect that I am only centring the mean. However, this code will not run.

I believe this is due to the `a1` matrix having two columns instead of one, but I really can't work out how to change this. I have tried adding a column of zeros and ones to the matrix, but I'm not sure if this will give me a correct result.

Of course, this may not be the issue at all, but I fail to see what else could be causing this. I have included the code and any advice would be appreciated.

```
    # Objective function
    objfn <- function(a1, X){
      sum(exp(X %*% a1))
    }

    # Gradient function
    gradfn <- function(a1, X){
      colSums(sweep(X, 1, exp(X %*% a1), "*"))
    }

    X.EM.0 = data$A-age.mean

    # Estimate weights
    print(opt1 <- optim(par = c(0,0), fn = objfn, gr = gradfn, X = X.EM.0, method = "BFGS"))
    a1 <- opt1$par
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a simple solution, I'm slightly embarrassed to have posted this.

`par=c(0,0)` should be altered to match the columns of data. Here it should have been changed to one.